# Docker swarm overlay Connect: no route to host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have a swarm with 2 nodes. One is an ubuntu VM on azure and the other one is my VM on my local machine.

When the containers try to make requests to each other with I get this `dial tcp 10.0.0.88:9999: connect: no route to host`

I've enabled in the 2 nodes all the swarm communication ports needed: tcp 2377 udp/tcp 7946 and udp 4789.

Communication works if I run everything local.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Taking docker out of the equation, can your Azure VM connect directly to your local VM?

Comment: No. My local VM has no public IP. That's why I'm trying to connect them with an overlay network. @BMitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overlay network doesn't create connectivity between two nodes, it requires connectivity, and then uses that to connect containers running on each node. From the prerequisites, each node needs to be able to reach the overlay ports on every other node in the cluster. See the documentation for more details:

https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

Comment: So I need to associate a public IP to my VM in order to get connectivity between containers in the same overlay network ?

Comment: @MLGonc you need connectivity from each node to every other node. A public IP is one way, a VPN would be another.